# Redirect URLs with page version to URL without version

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some links on my website with page version and i want visitors redirected to the same page but without version number.

example:

```
example.com/folder/locatedpage?v=1
example.com/folder/locatedpage?v=2
example.com/folder/locatedpage?v=3
```

i need any visitor open links like this should be redirected to:

```
example.com/folder/locatedpage
```

Without `?v=1`

So if i share a line with `?v=1` it automatically will redirect the visitor to the URL without `?v=1`

I tried many solutions here but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=\d+$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=301,L]
```

You may have to add additional conditions though, other logic might get broken. This obviously depends on your setup we do not know.

Comment: I found another code yesterday for a specific URLs, but i like your code its work for all website links that mean i don't need to repeat the code for each pages i need. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove a 'v' argument from an individual page by having something like the below in the code, does that do what you are looking for?

```
<script>
var url = new URL(location);
url.searchParams.delete('v');
history.replaceState(null, null, url);
</script>
```

Comment: The question reads as if the OP is looking for a server side solution.